# Weird sounds when running ncurses applications on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, ncurses

I get high pitch sounds when running applications build with ncurses in the terminal of an OS X 10.7.2 machine.
They stop immediately when the program is terminated.

Any ideas on what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that program is sending BELL character which is interpreted as sound.

Read this:
http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Visual-Bell.html#s7

And also this:
http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/110

Basically this interpreted by terminal, so I expect this article helps you to finally solve it:

https://superuser.com/questions/163994/how-can-i-get-the-mac-terminal-to-not-beep

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It's not the bell sound, it's not even coming from my speakers..  the sound is most likely coming from my CPU. I disabled the audible bell, as told in the superuser question, but the constant sound (similar to a hard disk seek) is still there...

Comment: Then I don't think this have nothing to do with ncurses library at all.